# Cannot create dylib for distribution that works on OS X 10.5 (building in 10.6 environment)

Tags: macos, gcc, cairo, homebrew, dylib

I'm trying to distribute cairo (1.10.2) with my application.  I can create the necessarily dylibs using Homebrew but they are dependent on versions of other dynamic libraries that aren't present in OS X 10.5 (libfontconfig, libfreetype, and others located primarily in `/usr/X11/lib`).

I assume to solve this I want it to be using the dylibs in `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/X11/lib` rather than the libraries in `/usr/X11/lib`. I've tried anything I could find for targeting cairo against the 10.5 SDK.

- Setting `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` environment variable to `10.5` (before calling `brew` or using Homebrew's `ENV`)
- Setting `SDKROOT` environment variable to "/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk" (before calling `brew` or using Homebrew's `ENV`)
- Adding `-mmacosx-version-min=10.5` to the `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, and `LDFLAGS` in the Homebrew formula for cairo.
- Adding `-sysroot`/`-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk` to the `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, and `LDFLAGS` in the Homebrew formula for cairo.
- Adding `-I$(SDKROOT)/usr/X11/include` and `-I$(SDKROOT)/usr/X11R6/include` to the `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` in the Homebrew formula for cairo.
- Adding `-L$(SDKROOT)/usr/X11/lib` and `-L$(SDKROOT)/usr/X11R6/lib` to the `LDFLAGS` in the Homebrew formula for cairo.

While building cairo it has `-I/usr/X11/lib` on the gcc commands (with my options tacked on the end) so I imagine it's hitting that first.  I'm not sure how to get rid of that so it uses my options.  I thought `isysroot` would make it so the include and library paths were rerooted in the SDK but `-isysroot` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: You might consider using MacPorts to supply the necessary 3rd-party libs for this use case rather than Homebrew.  MacPorts generally supports cross-release and -architecture building.  Just edit the settings files in `/opt/local/etc/macports` and `/opt/local/etc/variants`.

Comment: I was originally using macports but couldn't seem to get it to build with the deployment target I wanted (tried universal_target).  With Homebrew I got the cairo dylib itself to support 10.5 (seemingly) but it still references those system libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `install_name_tool` to change where cairo looks for its libraries. (I have no idea what cairo is. I'm assuming it's a dylib. If not, my confidence in this solution goes down considerably.)

Here's a made-up example that you should be able to adapt.

First, use `otool -L` to see which libraries cairo is using. In this example I'm working with libopencv_imgproc.2.3.1.dylib, but you'll use your cairo library's file name instead:

```
$ otool -L libopencv_imgproc.2.3.1.dylib 
libopencv_imgproc.2.3.1.dylib:
    lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.3.0, current version 2.3.1)
    lib/libopencv_core.2.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.3.0, current version 2.3.1)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
```

Then use `install_name_tool -change` to change whichever paths you need to change. The first parameter is the current library path, the second is the desired library path, and the third is the library file. I'm telling it to look for `libz.1.dylib` in `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/X11/lib/` instead of `/usr/lib`:

```
$ install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/X11/lib/libz.1.dylib libopencv_imgproc.2.3.1.dylib
```

Repeat this for every library whose path you need to change. `otool -L` shows us that the change was made:

```
$ otool -L libopencv_imgproc.2.3.1.dylib 
libopencv_imgproc.2.3.1.dylib:
    lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.3.0, current version 2.3.1)
    lib/libopencv_core.2.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.3.0, current version 2.3.1)
    /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/X11/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
```

In my example (and perhaps in your application) my library expects to find itself somewhere other than my application bundle, so I need to change that as well with `install_name_tool -id`. I'm copying the library to my application bundle's *Frameworks* folder so I'm telling it to look there:

```
$install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_imgproc.2.3.1.dylib libopencv_imgproc.2.3.1.dylib
```

You can put the `install_name_tool` invocations in a Run Script build phase. If you are copying the library into your application bundle's *Frameworks* folder, you should prepend the library name with `$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH/` to ensure that the script can find the library.

Comment: This should get me there, I think.  I've been using [macdylibbundler](http://macdylibbundler.sourceforge.net/) to pull cairo into my bundle and fix my executable's dylib path to it but it's set up (rightly) to ignore libraries in /usr/lib (as they should be on the user's system already).  I didn't know how to change the paths stored in the dylib manually though so you've helped me solve that so I should be able to handle any remaining issues.

[Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) is the vector graphics library used by GTK+, Firefox, and many others.