# dyld not loaded Reason: image not found libopencv_core.2.4.dylib

Tags: xcode, opencv, dylib

I'm still quite new to Objective C and Xcode, but I just finished a small app that uses the openCV `libopencv_core.2.4.2.dylib`.

When I went to open the final built app on **another machine**, OS X threw me this error:

```
Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded: */libopencv_core.2.4.dylib  
Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/my
app.app/Contents/MacOS/my app   
Reason: image not found
```

Why is my app looking for 2.4 instead of 2.4.2 here?

What I already checked:

I added a new build phase -> so that `libopencv_core.2.4.2.dylib` is copied to the app package (via "Copy Bundle Resources" in Xcode) - `libopencv_core.2.4.2.dylib` now lies in my `app.app/Resources`

What did I miss? Do I have so set some more library search paths or similar?

What I also did:

```
install_name_tool -id "@executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_core.2.4.2.dylib" libopencv_core.2.4.2.dylib
```

Copying the dylib to the Frameworks directory doesn't work either:

```
Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_core.2.4.2.dylib
```

Don't know what to do now - the dylib *is* in the Frameworks directory of my app...

Using `otool -L` on the binary gives me:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 19.0.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_core.2.4.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.2)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_highgui.2.4.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.2)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.2)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 945.11.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 744.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 407.7.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1187.33.0)
```

Comment: Did you check (using `otool -L`) that your use of `install_name_tool` actually changed the reference within your binary?

Comment: it did yes. i consider using opencv as a private framework instead. i downloaded one - but it seems it won't compile for x86_64 ?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you running `install_name_tool` on your **binary** (not the `.dylib`)?

Comment: I opened the .app package and ran it on the .dylib inside the .app. Still I'm not sure if this is the right way to distribute an app with openCV.

Comment: What about the binary?  Try an `otool -L` on that...

Comment: it gives me: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib (which sounds fine now) But It's strange because I always used **libopencv_core.2.4.2.dylib**  Why is my app suddenly searching for another version of the dylib?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7170560/76810

Comment: Yes that helped - Thats a good way. Thanks. I now have it all running - but I also tried a different way - compiling the dylibs with the @path in them in Xcode. thats solved everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution: recompiling openCV in Xcode and set the `@executable_path/../Frameworks` in the build settings, for every .dylib you compile - now the `.dylibs` themselves always "know where they are".

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with opencv built with Homebrew, and this seems like a really cumbersome solution. Did you ever find a better one?

Comment: @escapecharacter Do what kunalg suggested. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. i keep all .dylib in system root directory **usr/lib** it working fine. At the run time .o file not get .dylib file path then it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Since other answers are not clear enough;

Assume your dylib files are located in `/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/*.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

will solve this problem. Be aware that `/usr/lib` is protected by system in MacOS, thus you should use `/usr/local/lib`.